# Javascript force async callback of third party function that can execute sync or async

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have troubles to unterstand how the following function from [this online javascript book (You-Dont-Know-JS)](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20%26%20performance/ch2.md) works? How does this function enable async behaviour when passed to a third party function (described in the next snippet) that may or may not execute async?

```
function asyncify(fn) {
    var orig_fn = fn,
        intv = setTimeout( function(){
            intv = null;
            if (fn) fn();
        }, 0 )
    ;

    fn = null;

    return function() {
        // firing too quickly, before `intv` timer has fired to
        // indicate async turn has passed?
        if (intv) {
            fn = orig_fn.bind.apply(
                orig_fn,
                // add the wrapper's `this` to the `bind(..)`
                // call parameters, as well as currying any
                // passed in parameters
                [this].concat( [].slice.call( arguments ) )
            );
        }
        // already async
        else {
            // invoke original function
            orig_fn.apply( this, arguments );
        }
    };
}
```

The link I provided also lists the following code example on how to execute `asyncify(..)`:

```
function result(data) {
    console.log( a );
}

var a = 0;

ajax( "..pre-cached-url..", asyncify( result ) );
a++;
```

Here `ajax(..)` is a third party function that may execute async or sync. To enforce an async callback of `result(..)` the author introduces `asyncify(..)` as an example. This will result in the console output always being `1` (async).

As far as I understand, the function fist defines two variables `orig_fn` to store the original function handle, `result()` in this case. And `intv` is the timer id returned from `setTimeout`.

```
var orig_fn = fn,
    intv = setTimeout( function(){
        intv = null;
        if (fn) fn();
    }, 0 )
;
```

- `setTimeout(..,0)` means what exactly? To execute immediately in the next run of the event loop?
- Why do we execute `fn()` in the callback function of `setTimeout` and the else statement in the return function? Isn't the function called twice this way when `ajax` operates async? First when the timer fires, which calls `fn()` and again when invoking `orig_fn.apply(this, arguments)`?
- Why is asyncify returning a function but also calling the function `fn` passed to it?

What does the following in the if statement mean and does `fn` even get called if `ajax` is synchronous?

```
fn = orig_fn.bind.apply(
                orig_fn,
                // add the wrapper's `this` to the `bind(..)`
                // call parameters, as well as currying any
                // passed in parameters
                [this].concat( [].slice.call( arguments ) )
            );
```

- Why is the parameter `fn` set to the original function? For me the variable `fn` is not even used after returning? Or is it a reference to `result()` which is now changed by adding `this` of the wrapper and the arguments? If so, why is `this` of the wrapper needed?

**I guess my main problem to understand this function is how the flow of this code works depending on how `ajax(..)` works (async or sync). Could someone please explain both cases with the steps that happen in between?**

Comment: Not read that book - example is very ugly and out of date. Just try to create some project which send ajax request and find info on internet when you find some problem (StackOverflow). Type on google JS sync async and find some tutorials

Comment: setTimeout - event loop - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ